# How to connect a YPG-625 keyboard to a modern Mac

Tags: music, driver

I'm trying to connect Yamaha's [YPG-625 musical keyboard](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalkeyboards/dgx_series/ypg-625/) to a Mac, but it seems like there are only USB-MIDI drivers for Mac OS 10.1.5-10.4.0. Is there a way to connect it to a system with OS X El Capitan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found out that, even though the keyboard page doesn't point to these drivers, the [generic USB-MIDI drivers](http://download.yamaha.com/usb_midi/) from Yamaha work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to connect my Yamaha to my Mac Sierra I downloaded USB-MIDI Driver for Mac OS X (10.5.x - 10.9.x) and it worked. You should try those one by one. One should work.

Comment: Can you link to said driver since OP seems unable to find it?

Comment: I found the drivers myself at the end of the day.

Just set my own answer as accepted, so that it's clear it's resolved.